# Robocopy files older than 1980

Tags: date, robocopy

I am copying some files with Robocopy, and files dated older than 1980 gets 1980 as timestamp.

I have files dated from 1977 that can`t keep their timestamp.

How can I set Robocopy to keep timestamps older than 1980?

Thank you

Comment: Is a bad thing happening when the timestamp is modified or is this a cosmetic or archivist interest?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news, `robocopy` won't support dates earlier than 1980.

[From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Remarks
>
> The MS-DOS date format can represent only dates between 1/1/1980 and
>   12/31/2107; this conversion fails if the input file time is outside
>   this range.

Third party utilities aren't necessarily subject to the same limitations and will be bound to whatever your filesystem supports in its date structs.